# show only MAX rows

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table which shows me workhours of postoffices, the problem is that sometimes there are duplicates: for example i have saturday showing twice from one postoffice with the same time.
Solution is to show only 1 saturday with MAX(ID), but i can't deal with that and tha think is that i don't have to show id in select.
this is my script

```
SELECT h.ID,
           h.POSTINDEX,
           H.LONGNAME_UA,
           h.SHORTNAME_UA,
           pt.LONGNAME_UA,
           h.parent_Id,
           WORKCOMMENT,
           INTERVALTYPE,
           TO_CHAR(TFROM, 'HH24:MI') AS TFROM,
           TO_CHAR(TTO, 'HH24:MI'),
           WD.NAME_UA,
           WD.NAME_EN,
           WD.NAME_RU,
           WD.SHORTNAME_UA,
           pt.isVPZ,
           lr.NAME_UA,
           lr.CODE
      FROM ADDR_PO_WORKSCHEDULE tt
        LEFT JOIN ADDR_POSTOFFICE h
          ON tt.POSTOFFICE_ID = h.ID
        INNER JOIN mdm_lockReason lr
          ON lr.id = H.LOCK_REASON
        INNER JOIN ADDR_POSTOFFICEtype pt
          ON pt.ID = H.POSTOFFICETYPE_ID
        INNER JOIN ADDR_PO_WORKDAYS wd
          ON wd.ID = tt.dayofweek
      where tt.datestop = TO_DATE('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') AND tt.postoffice_id = 8221
      HAVING MAX(tt.ID)
      ORDER BY h.postIndex,
               h.POSTOFFICETYPE_ID,
               dayofweek,
               intervaltype,
               tFrom,
               tto
```

as you can see there i've add **HAVING MAX(tt.ID)** but i understand that it is incorrect and don't know how to solve that. help please!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here with no `having` and with tt.id as tt_id>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by tt_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as following:

```
Select * from
(Select <your select column list>,
Row_number() over (partition by h.postindex, trunc(tfrom) order by tt.id desc nulls last) as rn
From <from clause>
Where <where clause>
)
Where rn = 1;
```

`group by` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the source of your duplicate rows is coming from the `ADDR_PO_WORKSCHEDULE` table, then you can just de-dupe it before you use it in the rest of your query:

```sql
SELECT 
  h.ID, h.POSTINDEX, h.LONGNAME_UA, h.SHORTNAME_UA, pt.LONGNAME_UA, h.parent_Id,
  WORKCOMMENT, INTERVALTYPE, TO_CHAR(TFROM, 'HH24:MI') AS TFROM, TO_CHAR(TTO, 'HH24:MI'),
  WD.NAME_UA, WD.NAME_EN, WD.NAME_RU, WD.SHORTNAME_UA, pt.isVPZ, lr.NAME_UA, lr.CODE
FROM (
  SELECT src.*
  FROM (
    SELECT t.*, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY tt.postoffice_id, tt.dayofweek -- Group by post office / day of week
        ORDER BY <order_columns> -- Rank rows within each group
      ) AS RowNum
    FROM ADDR_PO_WORKSCHEDULE t
  ) src
  WHERE RowNum = 1
) tt
LEFT JOIN ADDR_POSTOFFICE h ON tt.POSTOFFICE_ID = h.ID
INNER JOIN mdm_lockReason lr ON lr.id = H.LOCK_REASON
INNER JOIN ADDR_POSTOFFICEtype pt ON pt.ID = H.POSTOFFICETYPE_ID
INNER JOIN ADDR_PO_WORKDAYS wd ON wd.ID = tt.dayofweek
WHERE tt.datestop = TO_DATE('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND tt.postoffice_id = 8221
ORDER BY h.postIndex, h.POSTOFFICETYPE_ID, dayofweek, intervaltype, tFrom, tto
```

Just replace  with the columns you want to use to decide which of the "duplicate" rows to keep.  If the order doesn't matter, just remove the `ORDER BY` altogether.

Also, you may want to qualify all column references, since you are selecting from multiple tables.